# observable value is not changed in agular html template

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

in my ngOnint I am calling the script, the value is showing in console.log but not reflecting in html template. userList is empty in template.

```js
getAllRoles(){
     this.adminService
    .getAllRoles().subscribe((users: any) => {
      this.userList =  users;
    });
    console.log("now",this.userList)
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML part?

Comment: actually the console.log and setting the userlist are not happening exactly after each other, you have to move the console log two lines above to get the actual value logged

Comment: If possible avoid the subscription in component.ts and store the response in observable `userList$: Observable<User[]]>;  this.userList$ = this.adminService.getAllRoles()`. After access the value with async pipe in template. PS.: Why do you get Users with a function called getAllRoles?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm thanks. "Why do you get Users with a function called getAllRoles?" i am getting it from bckend call to show it in template. if I avoid the subscription then how will i handle the subscription. you mean that i handle the subscription in service?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```js
getAllRoles(){
    this.adminService.getAllRoles().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((users: any) => {
      this.userList = [...users];
      console.log("now",this.userList);
    });
}
```